# Possible to get python source code from pyinstaller app?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyinstaller

So I'm working on a web scraping project right now and it's pretty specific; however, I have found a great project on the internet that was made with Pyinstaller. I have tried to reach out to the developer, but I think the code has been dead for a while. However, it would really help me with my project to see the logic in the code. Is there any way to deconstruct a pyinstaller app and view the source code?

Some more info:

So I have managed to use uncompyle6 and pyinstxtractor.py to look at the files within the initial .exe file. Within that, there was another .exe file with the same name as the app that I decompiled too. However, both of these directories just contained a lot .pyc files that appear to just be external modules. Within the innermost .exe, there is a file with the same name as the app but with no extension. I assume this is the main code, but when I open it in a text editor, it just looks like this, with little bits of readable code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pc5nH.jpg. I have scavenged the internet for this and found nothing, so any little piece of advice is invaluable. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes, very, very easily.  Shipping python files in an executable is easy game for anyone to decompile.  That is why most companies use service as software.

It's hard to say.  Could you link the project you are after?  I might take a crack and see if I can decompile it.  If the text files aren't there it is worth noting it could be cythonised or even compiled atypically meaning good luck to you cracking that.